# DJANGO: Serving static with NGINX/gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I can't seem to get static files loading properly with NGINX.

Strangely if I go to [MY-server-IP]:8001   which is the port assigned with gunicorn, The files load

But if I just go to [MY-server-IP] in the browser the page loads but none of the static does.

Here is my nginx settings:

```
server {
    server_name [MY-IP];

    access_log off;

    location ~ ^ /static/ {
        alias /django-app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
         alias /django-app/SENECA-DJANGO/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://[MY-IP]:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"'; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you really have `/django-app/` in root?

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes I do, is that a terrible idea? django-app is a virtual environment.

Comment: Not terrible, just unusual. It's common error to put incomplete path to root/alias, so I just check.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use the “^~” modifier in the static location? Unless it's a typo, you appear to be using a regular expression in your /static/ location anchored to a leading space.

```
location ^~ /static/ {
    alias /django-app/static/;
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. I just added it recently to see if there would be a difference. Strangely it deactivates all access to the site via [My-IP] but [My-IP]:8001 still works. This isn't an answer though... move to comments?

Comment: @AllTheTime, I've added some detail. The location stanza is formated better in an answer block, but I'll move this to comments if you want.

Comment: It's just that it doesn't address my issue and/or solve my problem